# date format back end

Tags: javascript, date, formatting

Hi I have a website that formats the date DD MM YYYY.
I have added the javascript code to the booking HTML page i created and works well!

The code is:

```
<script>
    $(function() {
        var defaultDate = new Date(); // = today

        $('#pickupdate').datepicker({
            changeMonth: true,
            dateFormat: 'dd mm yy',
            defaultDate: defaultDate, // set the default date of the picker
        }).datepicker('setDate', defaultDate); // set the text date value of the input

        // other code to run on document.ready...
    });

</script>
```

However, when the form submits I receive an email with the customer booking details but the date is YYYY MM DD.

How do i get the form to read DD MM YYYY when I receive the emailed booking form?

Comment: you can actually save your self from all these headaches. use moment

Comment: There's a lot that happens between the datepicker and you receiving an email. You need to test it at different stages to verify where it changes. And this code is definitely not where it's failing.

Comment: Yes, i think it is the server part - I have the form method as post action submit.php and the results get emailed to me. So I have a feeling i need some code in the PHP to convert it in the server before it gets emailed to me... maybe?

Comment: my php form also has this code: <tr>
<td>Date</td><td>'.$_POST['date'].'</td>
</tr>

Comment: @Lokesh—that is a pointless comment without some indication of how that particular library can help.

Comment: @RobG I mean OP can format the date using moment and send the date value in json format to the back end. This will make sure the date format is not being changed